# Trouble querying ListField with mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm using mongoengine, and I've got the following situation,

My model:

```
class Item(Document):
   ...
   tags = ListField(StringField(max_length=30))
```

The query:

```
filters = {
    'tags__contains': query
}
tags_with_counter = Item.objects.filter(**filters).item_frequencies('tags')
```

This returns a list of tuples containing the name of the tag, and the frequency. What I want to do is get only tags that contain **query** and their respective frequency. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you describe the end goal/use-case of this query in more detail? Are there a finite set of tags to choose from?  Do you just want the count of documents with tags containing query? why is the above item_frequencies query not sufficient for your needs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Having this similar MongoEngine model and documents:

```
class Post(Document):
    title = StringField()
    tags = ListField(StringField())

post1 = Post(title='Fun with MongoEngine', tags=['mongodb', 'mongoengine']).save()
post2 = Post(title='Loving Mongo', tags=['mongodb']).save()
```

You'll store this:

```
{
  "tags": [ "mongodb", "mongoengine" ],
  "title": "Fun with MongoEngine"
}
{
  "tags": [ "mongodb" ],
  "title": "Loving Mongo"
}
```

In MongoDB, when you run `find()` it returns the documents that match your query.

So with the following query, you'll get an array of documents (Post objects) that have the tag `mongodb` in the array field `tags`. (actually, the 'tag' array is joined with an empty string and matched if contains value 'mongodb'):

```
Post.objects(tags__contains='mongodb')
```

([filter](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.filter) is just an alias of objects constructor)

So after you get the item frequencies, you need to get the ones you're interested.

```
tag_cloud = Post.objects(tags__contains='mongodb').item_frequencies('tags')

> print tag_cloud
{'mongodb': 2, 'mongoengine': 1}
> tag_cloud['mongodb']
2
```

Comment: if I need to find any ? for example if tag is *